# How to correctly retrieve each selected value from a multiselect listbox array (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a multiselect listbox that is populated with concatenated values (consisting of a loaned item's item ID no. and item name) when a cbo box is updated (loaner's name selected).

Essentially, I would like to be able to recall, or refer to, the first concatenated value of each list item selected. The following code is my attempt at saving values of the listbox in an array whilst trying to incorporate the recalling of only the first concatenated value of each selection.

This code functions, however for some reason it only recalls the last selected value. For example, if the following list box items are selected; `"1:Anthropometric Tape Measure"` and `"2:Anthropometric Measuring Kit"` then the values reported (in a msgbox for troubleshooting purposes) are `"2,2"` IF the second item is selected last, instead of `"1,2"`.

What is strange is that if I use the array code without referring to only the first concatenated value, (`tmpArray(selCount) = lbox.List(i)` instead of `Split(lbox.List(lbox.ListIndex), ":")(0)`) the code functions correctly.

Any advice on fixing this would be extremely appreciated, thanks!

```
Public Function GetSelectedItems(lbox As Object)

Dim tmpArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim selCount As Integer
    selCount = -1

    For i = 0 To lbox.ListCount - 1

        If lbox.Selected(i) = True Then

            selCount = selCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray(selCount)
            tmpArray(selCount) = Split(lbox.List(lbox.ListIndex), ":")(0)
        End If
    Next

    If selCount = -1 Then

        GetSelectedItems = ""
    Else:
        GetSelectedItems = Join(tmpArray, ", ")
    End If

End Function
```

I am using the following code to recall the array into the message box (FYI).

```
Dim mySentence As String

mySentence = GetSelectedItems(Me.ListItem)

  Msg = "You selected" & vbNewLine & mySentence
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem:**

- Use of `Lbox.ListIndex`

**Answer:**

- Instead have to use `i`. Above refereed to the selected Item in Single Selection ListBox. i will give the correct Index of the Selected Item in Multiple Selection.

**Code:**

```
Public Function GetSelectedItems(lbox As Object)

Dim tmpArray() As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim selCount As Integer
    selCount = -1

    For i = 0 To lbox.ListCount - 1

        If lbox.Selected(i) = True Then

            selCount = selCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve tmpArray(selCount)
            tmpArray(selCount) = Split(lbox.list(i), ":")(0)

            Set fnd = Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("B11:B19").Find(Split(lbox.list(i), ":")(0))

            If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

                  fnd.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Selected"

            End If


        End If
    Next

    If selCount = -1 Then

        GetSelectedItems = ""
    Else:
        GetSelectedItems = Join(tmpArray, ", ")
    End If

End Function
```

Change the Worksheet Name & Range

Demo:

[image]

Comment: Well, that was easy. Thanks once again Mikku, greatly appreciated. Sorry for such a simple error.

Comment: If I want to refer directly to each individual value retrieved; for example with the above - if I wanted to say update the appropriate items `1` and `2` to 'Available' from 'On Loan' (within an inventory spreadsheet), would I need to write some kind of loop instead of recalling all selected values at once? The code works perfectly for individual values, but it doesn't like it when there are multiple values selected - not even when I remove the comma, or place them on separate lines.

Comment: Either you can Write a Loop for that, or involve that in the loop you currently in the above function.

Comment: @JoelMcWilliam , i have added another loop that might be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks for that @Mikku! However, it is now only registering the first value in the list. If I have `1` and `2` selected it will only recognise that `1` is selected. So puzzling.

Comment: @JoelMcWilliam , Maybe you are not putting the Code at the right place. I have changed the Answer Accordingly. Try this. Added a Demo as Well. And Again Probably a new question if it doesn't work out :) All the Best